# How do I change the Read-only file attribute for each file in a folder using c#?

Tags: c#

How do I change the Read-only file attribute for each file in a folder using c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

```
foreach (string fileName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);

    fileInfo.Attributes |= System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
    // or
    fileInfo.IsReadOnly = true;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this : iterate on each file and subdirectory :

```
public void Recurse(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    foreach (FileInfo fi in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        fi.IsReadOnly = false; // or true
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in directory.GetDirectories())
    {
        Recurse(subdir);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [File.SetAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx) in a loop iterating over [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to remove the readonly attributes using pattern matching (e.g. all files in the folder with a .txt extension) you could try something like this:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt").ToList().ForEach(file => new FileInfo(file).Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal);
```