# Change permissions of folders

Tags: c#, file-permissions, permission-denied

I want to change some folder permissions (set to Read-Only) to ReadWriteExecute!

I wrote this code, but the folder permission is still Read-Only:

```
private void ChangePermissions(string folder)
{
    string userName = Environment.UserName;

    FileSystemAccessRule accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(userName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit 
                | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);

    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
    DirectorySecurity directorySec = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();


    directorySec.AddAccessRule(accessRule);
    directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySec);
}
```

If I want delete this directory with `Directory.Delete(folder, true)` I get this error message:

> "Access to the path 'entries' is denied."

Sure, the permissions are still Read-Only!

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
dirInfo.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

This uses the bitwise logical AND operator [(&=)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/e669ax02(v%3dvs.120)) to append to the existing Attributes property the inverse of `FileAttributes.ReadOnly` (because `~` is bitwise NOT).

Comment: Same error. The 'entries' path is a file in the folder, maybe I must recursively change the permissions?! (but I dont understand why the Read-Only flag is still set to root folder?)

Comment: If you need to recursively change the file permissions, this SO post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191399/how-do-i-change-the-read-only-file-attribute-for-each-file-in-a-folder-using-c

Comment: Thx. With the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191399/how-do-i-change-the-read-only-file-attribute-for-each-file-in-a-folder-using-c all went fine!

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub permissions are handled using FileAttributes