# How do I grant permission for the application folder to full access during installation in a target machine?

Tags: c#, .net

I am including a MS access database(.mdb) file in a application folder during installation.
I can able to read/write to a .mdb file in my admin user account.

But when I install my set up in a target machine which is a limited user account, application folder becomes read-only.

How do I grant permission for the application folder to full access during installation in a target machine?

I read other post related to this problem but I am not able to success on it

I am using visual studio 2010. language: c#

Comment: what about this link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175270/change-permissions-of-folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do one of the following:

You could modify your application manifest to run the application as administrator.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

OR

You could place the mdb file in folder other than Program Files.
Typically files that need write access in an application are placed in

```
C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\<Manufacturer>\<Product>\<Product Version>
```

To get the Application Data folder path, use the following:

```
string applicationDataFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Comment: How to give a file path which works on both windows xp and windows 7?
because in windows xp the path goes like this c:\Documents and settings\username\application data
but in windows 7 its like this C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\

How can i give connection string which refers to the application data folder in both windows xp and 7?